# St. Petersburg's Paradox elaboration

Tags: probability, statistics

Find N (the entrance fee in dollars) such that you would expect to break even if you played the St. Petersburg's lottery every minute of every day of your life.

For more information on the St. Petersburg lottery, see the Wikipedia entry: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St._Petersburg_paradox

---

**Edit**

I'm going to assume the topic-closers closed this topic because they weren't sure which question I was asking.  That is, break even and stop, or break even and keep playing anyway.

Both.  Or neither.  Or pick your own version!!!